# How to avoid the repetitive results in minimum coin algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

```
def getways(n,c):
    for i in c:
        if i == 0:
            return
        if(n-i >=  0):
            getways(n-i,c)

n = 4
c = [1,2,3]
getways(n,c)
```

I have to tell all the unique combinations to make a sum. For example, for 4 the solution is (1,1,1,1),(1,1,2),(2,2),(1,3).
But my algorithm is computing all the permutations, as you can see in the image also. Now the question is how can I avoid completely computing those solutions which are repetitive, after I got to a certain solution single time?
Also I am including a code sample which is simply making the tree which I pasted in image. How can I append all these solutions to a list without passing a global variable containing list?

[image: 1]

Comment: *"my algorithm is computing all the permutations"*: I don't see that happening in your code. Your function returns nothing.

Comment: Yes, it is simply generating the tree , shown in image

Comment: i had included , two question , one how to avoid computing the redundant solutions ,and second how to output a list containing the solution without passing a global varibale

Comment: I don't see a tree anywhere in your code.

Comment: Could you add some print in the getways code that print the values shown on the paper?

Comment: I mean to say , it is generating the same sequence , as in the image solution ,and please try to help me , as i know , you are thinking the problem to be funny , but for me it is a serious issue

Comment: I do not know , anything the solutions cannot be printed at once , as my solution is formed from the choice of i or the order in which i is chosen  as , say (1,1,1,1,1) , this is generated when all the subsequent recursive call have i as 1 , so to print the complete solution ,we have to use something like list and append to  it , that i am asking already

Answer (score 0):

One way this can be done is by using the following recursion pattern:

One call of the function deals with one coin only. Either:

- it is used, and a recursive call is made with the same coin, but reduced amount
- it is not used, and a recursive call is made with the same amount, but the coin made unavailable for further use. This will guarantee that you don't get a permutation of the same solution.

Python is strong on iterables, so I would suggest making the function a generator, using `yield`, instead of returning a list of lists.

May I also suggest not using one-letter names. It is best practice to use descriptive names.

Suggested code:

```
def getways(amount, coins, firstcoin=0):
    if amount == 0:
        yield []  # start a way
        return
    if firstcoin >= len(coins) or amount < 0:
        return  # no ways
    yield from getways(amount, coins, firstcoin + 1)
    for way in getways(amount - coins[firstcoin], coins, firstcoin):
        yield [coins[firstcoin]] + way  # populate the way
```

Example call:

```
amount = 4
coins = [1,2,3]
print(*getways(amount, coins))
```

For this example input, the output will be:

```
[2, 2] [1, 3] [1, 1, 2] [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

If you want to have the list, then just use the `list` function:

```
lst = list(getways(amount, coins))
```

NB: I omitted the zero-check that you had. The coins should not have zero-coins. If you want to check that, then also check that `coins` is a list, and only has integers, that they are not negative, and also check that the target amount is a non-negative integer, ...etc.

### With less recursion

For large amounts which may be split in thousands of coins, the above will lead to too much recursion. In that case you can introduce the loop (like you also did) in the following way:

```
def getways(amount, coins, firstcoin=0):
    if amount == 0:
        yield []  # start a way
        return
    if firstcoin >= len(coins) or amount < 0:
        return  # no ways
    # Vary between not using this coin at all
    #   and using it up to the maximum possible times:
    for count in range(0, amount // coins[firstcoin] + 1):
        for way in getways(amount - count * coins[firstcoin], coins, firstcoin + 1):
            yield [coins[firstcoin]] * count + way  # populate the way
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir , it will help me to learn a lot of new things